# When do we perform Cache invalidation?

Tags: caching, cache-invalidation

An excerpt from Wiki on Cache invalidation -
"Cache invalidation is a process in a computer system whereby entries in a cache are replaced or removed." But, why on earth do we need to invalidate Cache?
I can think of only possible scenario - 
If for some reason cache and the database go out of sync, the data in cache will be stale. To sync it, we will need to invalidate cache. But, the cache and DB going of sync(except for a short period of time when the data is yet to be written into both) is not a desirable behaviour. So, cache invalidation acts as a remedy if we discover that the cache does not contain the correct data. Is this its sole purpose?

Comment: You imply, that "someone" refreshes the cache with the "new" data if the underlying data structure changes, but that is not true as a cache is only filled on a need-to-use-basis. I.e., if the underlying data changes, remove the stale data and wait if the cache would be needed in future. And if yes, re-fill it.

Comment: I don't think you realize that `Cache and DB going out of sync` event is too frequent to have it claimed just as an *undesirable*  behavior. It happens more often than just a few times, and your business logic **should be affected** by it. Otherwise why else are you even caching?

Comment: @Smutje - There are different cache updating strategies. I think updating one 'need-to-use-basis' comes under 'Write around cache' policy. In write back and write through policies, we update cache and DB.

Comment: Cache and DB out of sync - too frequent ? I know that happens in 'write around cache' policy. Consider 'write through' or 'write back' cache updating policies. In that, they won't be out of sync for too long.

Comment: Just for the record: please try to be as specific as possible. You see, this community is for specific questions on programming. It is not a place where we have lengthy discussions (by asking more and more questions using comments). From that point of view, you might want to look to the [help] to learn how and what to ask here.

Comment: First of all please follow GhostCat's Comment on how to ask question. Your query is becoming unclear. In order that you understand my comment, I present the following statements: in your original post, you are asking When cache validation is needed, and answered your own question by mentioning `when DB and cache is out of sync.` My point was you saying `.. DB / Cache out of sync is not a desirable behavior`, may be a result of not addressing such issues frequently.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin: Thanks.'answered your own question by mentioning.....'  .....I know that is one reason for cache invalidation...but I intended to know whether there is any other reason.

Comment: @GhostCat - have you deleted your answer? It was there in the afternoon and now, I cannot see it anymore.

Comment: @GhostCat - I do not why anybody downvoted it. I do not have any reputation..It is my first question after all !! Your answer was good. Explains one of the scenarios where cache invalidation is performed. I will accept it. Post it again.

Comment: I brought it back two hours ago, simply refresh the page?!

Answer (score 2):

Cache invalidation exists because most caches operate based upon a trade-off of performance vs capacity.

Consider a solid state drive vs a hard drive. The performance of the SSD will be better but the amount of data you can store will be worse at the same cost level. Often people will combine them to get the performance of an SSD for frequently accessed files (such as the operating system), and a HDD for raw storage capacity.

CPUs are structured in a similar hierarchy, where the closest to the CPU is the fastest but also the smallest. The costs in this case are not necessarily just monetary cost but also physical space, power usage, heat production etc.

1. CPU registers - fastest, very small
2. CPU caches (also have their own hierarchy) - fast, small
3. RAM - medium, large

To keep the caches performing at their best, the most frequently accessed items must be maintained so that there is a better ratio of cache hits to misses. We want to be fetching from our slower sources as infrequently as possible. Similarly, because of the limited size constraint, we need to evict the items which are accessed least frequently.

Cache invalidation is the strategy which we will utilise in order to decide which items to evict and when, in order to make space for newer items which have a higher likelihood of being required again. It is not applicable if your cache contains a full representation of some other data source.